# What is christian suffering like in a 1st world country

Tags: suffering, persecution, 1-peter

In 1 Peter 1:6-7 he talks about suffering being necessary in a Christian's life which at the time, I believe, was prison or death and in the time of Nero suffering for being a Christian was a very real fact.

Today however, in first world countries being a christian in some places gives the person a high social status, while in other first world countries the worst form of persecution is online mockery. That's not to say that there isn't any suffering or pain but to say that there isn't one that's caused by being a christian.

So my question is, as a christian living in a first world country am I doing something wrong? Is the absence of suffering (at least anywhere close to the one received by first century christians) indicates that I am not living as a christian should live?

Comment: I like this question, but as it stands it may be a little too broad. Some live as if in 3rd world countries. Then there is the question of pain and depression...

Comment: I think you're referring to their financial situation, which whether or not they're a Christian they would still experience. But in some third world countries going to church is a risk, churches get bombed and burned frequently in the middle east even in cities that are far away from any warzones such as Cairo, Egypt.

Comment: Hence these are indeed suffering because they're Christians, but in the democratic first world it's hard to find an example of a person being persecuted for their faith, with the exception of people that have something to lose such as Israel Folau (Even though I disagree that what he tweeted was an innocent verse from the bible) but other than that, a normal middle working class christian (or at least if i speak for myself) is living a pretty normal life

Comment: I like the question too. Very insightful and needed. However it does not follow the required format to be included in this forum: what does X denomination hold about Y text with regard to Z doctrine. This is more like Wiki, informs, not pokes. Please post the question in other websites that allow discussion.

Comment: The main source of the persecution of professing Christians (in countries where law and order prevails strongly) is from other professing Christians. In my own experience and by my own observation. This persecution manifests itself particularly in the exclusion of certain professing Christians from the gatherings of other professing Christians.

Comment: @NigelJ can you elaborate please

Comment: I answered your question in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/1167/52516754) . Maybe it will help you reformulate your question to comply with site requirements.

Comment: Or you can read my answer in the  question I rephrased here https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/74142/what-did-paul-believe-about-1-corinthians-104-with-regards-to-the-teaching-abou

Comment: Nigel is on the right track in his comment. Jesus said the world would hate his followers. So it is that regardless of where they live true Christians are objects of ridicule and disdain for holding fast to beliefs and practices that are eschewed by  professing Christians who follow traditions and teachings of men rather than the teachings of the Bible.